# SQL update multiple rows with different values where they match a value from a list

Tags: sql, sql-update

So perhaps the title is a little confusing. If you can suggest better wording for that please let me know and i'll update.

Here's the issue. I've got a table with many thousands of rows and i need to update a few thousand of those many to store latest email data.

For example:

OldEmail@1.com => NewEmail@1.com

OldEmail@2.com => NewEmail@2.com

I've got a list of old emails ('OldEmail@1.com','OldEmail@2.com') and a list of the new ('NewEmail@1.com','NewEmail@2.com'). The HOPE was was to sort of do it simply with something like

```
UPDATE Table 
SET Email = ('NewEmail@1.com','NewEmail@2.com')
WHERE Email = ('OldEmail@1.com','OldEmail@2.com')
```

I hope that makes sense. Any questions just ask. Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Put the mapping list in a separate table. Then do `UPDATE tablename SET email = coalesce((select max(newmail) from mappingtable where oldmail = email), email)`

Comment: Put your pairs `(value, replacement)` into a table form in CTE/subquery (or save in temporary or static table), then update by the common way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression:

```
update mytable
set email = case email
    when 'OldEmail@1.com' then 'NewEmail@1.com'
    when 'OldEmail@2.com' then 'NewEmail@2.com'
end
where email in ('OldEmail@1.com','OldEmail@2.com')
```

Or better yet, if you have a large list of values, you might create a table to store them (like `myref(old_email, new_email)`) and join it in your update query, like so:

```
update t
set t.email = r.new_email
from mytable t
inner join myref r on r.old_email = t.email
```

The actual syntax for update/join does vary accross databases - the above SQL Server syntax.

Comment: This does kind of make sense but the issue is I have quite literally got thousands of rows to update so it would be a very time consuming task to write a case for each :/

Comment: @rubidge96 you can use multiple cursor in azure data studio, or vs code. Do middle click and drag, or alt + shift + left click. This will allow you to type in thousands of rows at once. helpful for other stuff too! If you want you could also use Excel or sheets.

Answer (score 1):

With accuracy to the syntax in particular DBMS:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT 'NewEmail@1.com' newvalue, 'OldEmail@1.com' oldvalue
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'NewEmail@2.com', 'OldEmail@2.com')
UPDATE table
SET table.email = cte.newvalue
FROM cte
WHERE table.email = cte.oldvalue
```

or, if CTE is not available,

```
UPDATE table
SET table.email = cte.newvalue
FROM (SELECT 'NewEmail@1.com' newvalue, 'OldEmail@1.com' oldvalue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'NewEmail@2.com', 'OldEmail@2.com') cte
WHERE table.email = cte.oldvalue
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) for rows update in large batches.

Basically it works as following :

- database complies a **query pattern** you provide the first time, keep the compiled result for current connection (depends on implementation).
- then you updates all the rows, by sending **shortened label of the prepared function** with different parameters in SQL syntax, instead of sending entire `UPDATE` statement several times for several updates
- the database parse the **shortened label of the prepared function**  , which is linked to the pre-compiled result, then perform the updates.
- next time when you perform row updates, the database may still use the pre-compiled result and quickly complete the operations (so the first step above can be skipped).

Here is [PostgreSQL example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-sql-prepare.html) of prepare statement, many of SQL databases (e.g. MariaDB,MySQL, Oracle) also support it.